# insert utf 8 encoding to sql db in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to insert into sql db japaneese character and it goes to db as ??? do you know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add "N" in front of the insert statement

```
insert into table values (1,2,N'Unicode text')
```